# How do you stop a For loop from progressing until a condition has been met?

Tags: procedural-programming

I have a matrix and the generation of a number between 0 and 1 (this number will act as a probability):

```
matrix1 = {{1, 0, 7, 5}, {0, 1, 8, 0}, {7, 8, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0, 1}};
prob = RandomReal[1]
```

I then have the following loop:

```
  For[q = 1, q <= 5, q++, {x = RandomInteger[{1, 4}];
  y = RandomInteger[{1, 4}];
  If[matrix1[[x, y]] == 0, matrix1[[x, y]] = 7, matrix1[[x, y]] = 0];
  Print[MatrixForm[matrix1]];
  probLoop = Print[RandomReal[1]];
  }]
```

A quick summary: The loop randomly picks an element position in `matrix1`, if there is a 0 in that position then 0 -> 7, if there's a nonzero integer in that position then integer -> 0.  The loop is currently set up so that it runs sequentially, starting from `matrix1` we then generate a matrix2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 (each subsequent matrix is a build off of the ones before it) and an integer between 0 and 1 (more on this below).

Instead of running `matrix1` continuously straight through the loop, I'd like to only continue the loop progression if the probability given by `prob` and `probLoop` allow for it.

[image]

In the example picture provided, we start with `matrix1` and then through one iteration of the loop we'd have the creation of `matrix2`.  The probability of `matrix1` converting into `matrix2` is given by `prob`(approx. 15% in this case).  So 15% of the time the matrix is converted into `matrix2` and the loop proceeds to the next round.  If `matrix1` fails to convert (approx. 85% chance), we just rerun `matrix1` again to create a new `matrix2` and a new probability for matrix conversion.

I would like to apply the above step-wise process for each loop iteration.  So once we generate a `matrix2`, it's only converted to `matrix3` given by the percentage chance given by the first listed output of `probLoop` (`matrix3` converts to 4 based upon the second given output of `probLoop`, etc).  If `matrix2` fails to update to `matrix3` then `matrix2` is just reran through the loop again to generate a new `matrix3` with a new probability and this cycle repeats itself until `matrix1` has converted into `matrix6`.

Comment: `probLoop = Print[RandomReal[1]]` does not assign a value to `probLoop` (well, it assigns `Null`, which is not what you want). `Print` has no return value. Use `Print[probLoop = RandomReal[1]]` instead.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, use a while loop inside the for loop, which terminates when the condition is met and allows the for loop to continue.

Comment: `For[q = 1, q <= 5, q++, {x = RandomInteger[{1, 4}]; ... }]` -  you don't need the `{ ... }` here for the body of the loop.